# Linq query to return all quotes for a specific category

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core

I have 2 models

```
public class GroupReaderModel
    {
        public string ProductId { get; set; }
        public string GroupName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<QuotesModel> Quotes { get; set; }
    }

public class QuotesModel
    {
        public string ProductId { get; set; }

        public DateTime AsOfDate { get; set; }

        public decimal Value { get; set; }
    }
```

I need a linq query to output all quotes for a specific GroupName.

```
var result = groups
                .Where(group => group.GroupName == "Test")    
                .Select(group => new GroupReaderModel                 
                {                                            
                    GroupName = group.GroupName,                 
                    Quotes = quotes         
                        .Select(quote => new QuotesModel    
                        {                                    
                            ProductId = quote.ProductId,                 
                            Value= quote.Value,              
                            AsOfDate= quote.AsOfDate,              
                        })
                        .ToList(),                           
                })
                .ToList();
```

This is the query i have so far, but it outputs all quotes to a specific group instead of only the ones that match ProductId

Comment: `context.GroupReaderModels.Where(x => g.GroupName = "some group name").SelectMany(x => x.Quotes).ToList()`

Comment: Did you try something yourself?

Answer (score 1):

`groupReaderModels.Where(g => g.GroupName == specifiedGroupName).FirstOrDefault()?.Quotes;`

**Edit:**
As Jappe rightly pointed out in the comments, you're most probably better off going with:
`.Where(g => g.GroupName == specifiedGroupName).SelectMany(g => g.Quotes);`

And if you expect only one result then you can guard yourself with:

`.Where(g => g.GroupName == specifiedGroupName).SingleOrDefault()?.Quotes;`

Which will throw an exception if there's more than one results.

Comment: Why `FirstOrDefault`? If there can be more than one, then how do you know the _first_ one is better? There is also `SingleOrDefault`. Or maybe the asker wants `.Where(g => g.GroupName == specifiedGroupName).SelectMany(g => g.Quotes)`.

Comment: You're right. I wrongly assumed there might be only one match. Cosmin most probably is looking for the ```.SelectMany(g => g.Quotes)```

Comment: When one assumes there is only one match, which is quite common (and we do not know what the asker wants), then in my opinion `SingleOrDefault` is much better than `FirstOrDefault`. Because if one's assumption fails for some reason, instead of just happily picking the first match (which must be problematic), it will guarantee you an `InvalidOperationException`.

Comment: I tried but still not working. I have 2 deserialized object with values and the output still don't work. for example in group model there are plenty of product id's specified to groupnames. I need to display a specific group name  for example "test group" and then match all productId's from quotes to groups and output all quotes

Answer (score 0):

```
 var groupReaderModel = new List<GroupReaderModel>();
 var quotes = (from gr in groupReaderModel
               where gr.GroupName == "<GroupName>"
               select gr.Quotes).ToList();
```

Comment: An explanation of the problem and why this works would be useful.